Why does the linker not work correctly when definitions are implemented in cpp file
I do not understand how to compile c++ code correctly. I have a test file using an example class and I continue to get the error:
user@MacBook-Pro Online-Order-OOP-Project % clang++ -std=c++11 -o test.out test.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Point::getX()", referenced from:
      _main in test-3f2ef3.o
  "Point::Point()", referenced from:
      _main in test-3f2ef3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It was my understanding that using the #include statements would handle the linking for me. How do I make this compile correctly?
Here is the test.cpp file:
#include "Point.h"
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    Point point;
    std::cout << point.getX() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Here is the Point.h file:
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;

    public:
        Point()  ;
        int getX() ;
        int getY() ;

};


#endif

and the Point.cpp file:
#include "Point.h"

Point::Point() {
            this->x = 0;
            this->y = 0;
} 
int Point::getX() {
    return this->x;
} 
int Point::getY() {
    return this->y;
} ;


you need to compile test.cpp and point.cpp into object files and then you link those files together.

clang++ -std=c++11 -o test.out test.cpp -> clang++ -std=c++11 -o test.out test.cpp Point.cpp

How would the compiler and linker know about the Point.cpp file if you don't tell them about it? And there's really no connection between a header file and a source file using similar names. The files could be named completely different. Especially considering that there's really no standard suffix for C++ source file, .cpp just happens to be one of the more common.

That said, some tools do autodetect cpp files and send them to the linker. As you can guess sometimes this approach leads to build mistake hilarity as well.  You just can't win.

@Yksisarvinen that solution should be posted as an answer.

@Yksisarvinen your answer works. How does that work because I include the Point.cpp to be compiled it links the Point.h correctly or something?

It looks like you are using other computer language's build steps to figure out how a C++ build works.  Don't do that.  There are two separate programs, the compiler and the linker.   The compiler's job is to create object code from the source modules.  The linker's job is to now take the generated object code, and resolve all of the function calls to make sure the functions actually exist that you are calling.  Yes you compiled main.cpp, and the compiler doesn't care if any of those Point functions actually exist.  It is the job of the linker to determine if those functions exist.

And note, this is not like other languages that automatically match file names to classes used (like Java for example) and "magically" things work.  You have to specify all modules to build, and even all modules to link.  Integrated environments makes this easier to handle, but under the hood of those environments is still the task of specifying all source modules to compile and link to produce the final executable (or library).

Does this answer your question? How to compile multiple files in g++ with extern

BTW, you can reduce the amount of typing by removing the this-> syntax.  If you need to use this-> consider renaming the member variables or the method parameter names.

Now seems like a good time to learn how the compiler really works, and about the concepts of translation units.
In short, a translation unit is a single source file with all included header files. It's the basic unit that the compiler is working with. The compiler will only know what is in the translation unit it's currently process, nothing else.
The program clang++ that you run isn't actually the compiler. Instead it's a front-end driver program which invokes the tools needed to build your source into an executable program.
The process of building a source file into a program follows multiple steps:

Preprocess the source file.
This includes all header files and expands all macros.
This step is usually embedded into the actual compiler, and not separate and distinct.

Actual compilation.
This takes the translation unit, compiles it into machine code, and outputs an object file.

Linking.
This is where all object files and libraries are combined to form the final executable program.


As mentioned above, step 1 and 2 are usually combined, but in the C++ specification is still considered separate phases. Step 2 (with step 1) and step 3 are usually performed by two different programs, that doesn't really know anything about each other.
And here comes the part that leads to your problem: You were building only the test.cpp source file. The clang++ program will tell the compiler to build that single file into an object file, and then tell the linker to use that single object file to create the executable program. No program will know about the Point.cpp source file.
You need to explicitly tell clang++ about all source files it should use.
